# How to implement instance numbering?

Tags: c#, .net

I don't know if the title is clear but basically I am trying to implement something like this:

```
public class Effect
{
    public int InternalId ...

    public void ResetName() ...
}
```

When ResetName is called, this will reset the name of the object to:

```
"Effect " + someIndex;
```

So if I have 5 instances of `Effect`, they will be renamed to:

```
"Effect 1"
"Effect 2"
"Effect 3"
...
```

So I have another method (`ResetNames`) in another manager/container type that calls `ResetName` for each instance. And right now I have to pass an integer to `ResetName` while keeping a counter myself inside `ResetNames`. But this feels not as clean and this prevents me from calling `ResetName` myself outside the manager class, which is valid.

How to do this better/cleaner?

As for the `InternalId`, it's just some id that stores the creation order for everything. So I can't just rely on these, because the numbers are large, like 32000, etc.

EDIT: Container ResetNames code:

```
int count = 1;
var effects = this.Effects.OrderBy ( n => n.InternalId );
foreach ( Effect effect in effects )
{
    effect.ResetName ( count );
    ++count;
}
```

Comment: It might help knowing if this code is supposed to be thread-safe or not.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't need to be thread-safe.

Comment: Can you add the code from the container that implements ResetNames to make this easier to follow?

Comment: You say that you would want to call ResetName yourself outside the manager class, but I don't see how that's valid.  ResetName appears to set the name of the object based on the object's position within a collection, and if the object is not in a collection, it really can't do anything.  ResetName would always have to be done within the context of a collection, right?

Comment: Sorry just posted the ResetNames.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: Effect instances are added to some sort of collection but I don't have access to it just for them. Above in ResetNames, I collect them and call ResetName for each. But if you call just ResetName, then it should still do reset the name, maybe the same number, but the other part of the name should be updated as well. Sorry to simplify I didn't mention more but the actual name is more complicated like "Effect " + ownerName + orderName + ..., so the reset of it should still update on call to ResetName.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: So to clear it: if other properties of the effect changes, the name should reset. In that case, it's acceptable to just update other parts except the number, so the number could be stored, but still the outside method requiring a number while other ResetName methods on other types do not.

Comment: So do you basically want to strip off the number, change the name and put the same number back on?

Comment: Depends, if I pass an integer to ResetName from ResetNames, I could store the number, but other implementations might require different approaches. Is this what you meant?

Comment: This is very confusing -- Does ResetName need to accomplish 2 different things?  Does it need to be able to 1. Change the part of the name before the number and 2. Change the name and number?  If so, see my answer below that stores the number and name separately.

Comment: No it has to do only 1 thing. Just update the name with the latest values. This is complicated internally but if some values on an effect instance is changed, and you called ResetName, those new values will be visible in the name, along with a number that's unique among other effect instances, and all these numbers will start from 1 to n. So can't be arbitrary numbers.

Comment: Then I think you can use my solution described below.  When you need to change the name, just change BaseName instead of calling ResetName.  When you need to re-index all the names, set the "Index" value on all the instances using the counter you already have.  I still think that's 2 things.  If you think this solution has a problem, add another comment to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a manager class that handles the naming. It will also handle creation of the child class, and will embed a reference to itself. You can now call `ResetName()` on the child class, and it will have it's manager handle whatever logic needs to be done.

I'm not sure exactly what you want the results to be in various situations, but hopefully the following will be of some help:

```
public class Effect {
{
  private EffectManager _manager;
  public string Name {get;set;}

  public Effect(EffectManager manager) {
    _manager = manager;
  }

  public void ResetName() {
    Name = _manager.GetNextName();
  }
}

public class EffectManager {
  private List<Effect> Effects;
  private int currentIndex;
  public Effect CreateEffect() {
    var e = new Effect(this);
    Effects.Add(e);
  }

  public string GetNextName() {
    return "Effect " + currentIndex++;
  }

  public void ResetAllNames() {
    currentIndex = 0;
    foreach(var effect in Effects) {
      effect.Name = GetNextName();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of many possibilities: give your Effect class a public property Name, and in the method where you populate a list or array of Effect objects, assign the name. You can also give the Effect class an integer property and set the number, so that you can sort them, if you want.

```
public class Effect() 
{  
  public string Name() { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClass()
{
  private List<Effect> Effects;

  public static void WhateverMethod()
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < Effects.Count; i++)
      Effects[i].Name = "Effect " + (i + 1).ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but don't think this would work. Because all effects are stored in a global collection that contains everything. So having another list means more bookkeeping, syncing. Also this doesn't address calls to ResetName for a single instance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having Name be a stored property, could you do something like this?

```
public class Effect
{
    public int InternalId ...
    public int Index;
    public string BaseName;
    public string Name
    {
       get
       {
          return BaseName + index;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think the problem with this is, if I need to reset the name from the outside then the reset name logic would have to be determined outside, also not sure why you are setting index to 0?

Comment: 0 means there is no number at the end of the name (in case you want to set the whole name to "My Object" with no number on the end, for example).  I'm confused about what kinds of names you need to store.  You would not need a ResetName in this case.  You could just change BaseName or Name directly.

Comment: The number always have to be present, otherwise it will break the rule of every effect having a number, from 1 to n.

Answer (score 0):

Are the names specific to all instance or to all instances in a given collection?

If the former you could do something like:

```
public class Effect
{
    private static int _lastId;

    public Effect()
    {
        InternalId = _lastId++;
    }
    public string Name 
    {
        get { return "Effect" + InternalId.ToString(); }
    }
    public int InternalId ...
}
```

Comment: Yep it's the former, but how it's gonna work if the user deletes some and creates some more? Or deletes some and calls ResetNames so all names has to start from 1 to n again?

Comment: Also another problem I see with this is, if the user saves the file and then reopens, next time, the counter will start from 0, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
Namespace Diagnostics

    <Conditional("DEBUG")> _
    Public NotInheritable Class UniqueID

        Private Shared _idBase As Integer

        Private Sub New()
            'keep compiler from creating default constructor
        End Sub

        Public Shared Function GetNext() As String
            Return "ID" + System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(_idBase).ToString("00")
        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please show me how this will be used in ResetName or ResetNames?

Comment: @Joan Venge: Instead of storing the number/index/counter in the manager/container, have the manager/container use a class that maintains the number/index/counter, as shown above. Then your objects can use GetNext. In your case, I would add a Reset method.